# Фокус на JWindow

Tags: java

Мне нужно сделать прослушивание клавы, но использовать JFrame нельзя, только JWindow. Выходит, что при нажатии ничего не происходит. На каком-то форуме мельком видел статью по этому поводу, но сейчас найти не могу.

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом. Даже если он не работает, у вас есть шанс получить квалифицированный ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Уже решил.
Создал JFrame, вписал прослушивание в него и вынес за пределы экрана.